# How to compute $\frac{d }{dt}\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

If $F$ is function about $x,t$ and we know that
$$
\frac{dF}{dt}\le g(x,t)
$$
Can we deduce that
$$
\frac{d \lVert F\rVert_{\infty}}{dt}\le \lVert g(x,t)\rVert_{\infty}
$$
where $\lVert f(x,t)\rVert_{\infty}=\inf_{M\in \mathbb{R}}\{M||(\{|f(x,t)|>M\}|=0\}$.

**My Effort**
$$
\frac{\lVert F\rVert_{\infty}(t_1)-\lVert F\rVert_{\infty}(t_2)}{t_1-t_2}=\frac{|F(y,t_1)|-|F(x,t_2)|}{t_1-t_2}\le \frac{|F(y,t_1)|-|F(y,t_2)|+|F(y,t_2)|-|F(x,t_2)|}{t_1-t_2}\le \\
\frac{|F(y,t_1)|-|F(y,t_2)|}{t_1-t_2}\le \frac{|F(y,t_1)-F(y,t_2)|}{t_1-t_2}
$$
where $|F(y,t_1)|=\lVert F\rVert_{\infty}(t_1),|F(x,t_2)|=\lVert F\rVert_{\infty}(t_2)$.
Hence, Let $t_2\to t_1$, we can obtain
$$
\frac{d \lVert F\rVert_{\infty}}{dt}\le |g(y,t)|\le \lVert g\rVert_{\infty}
$$

However, this proof is almost right, since there is a zero measure set $|F(y,t_2)|>|F(x,t_2)|$.

**Update**:Actually, we can use the following inequality to get a proof.
$$
\frac{\lVert F\rVert_{\infty}(t_1)-\lVert F\rVert_{\infty}(t_2)}{t_1-t_2}\le \frac{|F(y,t_1)|-|F(x,t_2)|}{t_1-t_2}+\epsilon\le \frac{|F(y,t_1)|-|F(y,t_2)|+|F(y,t_2)|-|F(x,t_2)|}{t_1-t_2}+\epsilon\le \\
\frac{|F(y,t_1)|-|F(y,t_2)|}{t_1-t_2}+\epsilon\le \frac{|F(y,t_1)-F(y,t_2)|}{t_1-t_2}+\epsilon
$$
where $|F(y,t_1)|>\lVert F\rVert_{\infty}(t_1)+\epsilon (t_2-t_1 ),|F(x,t_2)|=\lVert F\rVert_{\infty}(t_2)$ and $|F(y,t_2)|\le \lVert F\rVert_{\infty}(t_2)$

Comment: The notation seems to be off: $\|F\|_\infty$ is a constant, thus its derivative is zero.

Comment: @gerw Note that $\lVert F\rVert_{\infty}$ depend on $t$

Comment: Then you should write down a proper definition of $\|F\|_\infty$.